# How To Choose A Random Line From A List And Display It In A Message box. C# Forms Application

Tags: c#

This is the list,
Tix Has A 40% Chance Of Winning Currently!
Tix Has A 41% Chance Of Winning Currently!
Tix Has A 42% Chance Of Winning Currently!
Tix Has A 43% Chance Of Winning Currently!
Tix Has A 44% Chance Of Winning Currently!
Tix Has A 45% Chance Of Winning Currently!
I need it to display in a message box, I have found how to do it in a console, but not in a form application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, use DateTime.Now.Ticks as a simple random number generator,

```
string[] messages = {"Tix Has A 40% Chance Of Winning Currently!"," Tix Has A 41% Chance Of Winning Currently! "," Tix Has A 42% Chance Of Winning Currently! "," Tix Has A 43% Chance Of Winning Currently! "," Tix Has A 44% Chance Of Winning Currently! "," Tix Has A 45% Chance Of Winning Currently!" };
MessageBox.Show(messages[(int) (DateTime.Now.Ticks % messages.Length)]);
//or:
MessageBox.Show(messages[new Random().Next(messages.Length)]);
```

Comment: A tip: `new Random().Next` will work properly in .NET Core or later only. For older versions it's better to instantiate the `Random` separately and once instead of per every `.Next()` call, otherwise it will generate the same number (same number sequence) for each instantiated copy of `Random`. For more details refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netcore-3.1#instantiating-the-random-number-generator).